# How does Flow type checking with the Redux store work?

Tags: javascript, redux, flowtype

I've seen code that goes like this:

```
import type { Store as ReduxStore } from 'redux';

export type Store = ReduxStore<State, Action>;
```

I don't understand what `<State, Action>` is doing. Is it passing type parameters to ReduxStore?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, they are type parameters.

> `export type Store = ReduxStore<State, Action>;`

This says that the type `Store` is a sort of `ReduxStore` that at any particular moment has a state of type `State`, and it reduces over actions of type `Action`.

https://github.com/flowtype/flow-typed/blob/41297ff31698506c0b398507101615e687bc9e54/definitions/npm/redux_v3.x.x/flow_v0.55.x-/redux_v3.x.x.js#L19-L24

Comment: That's weird, I found this (https://redux.js.org/glossary#store) on the Redux docs and the type definition for store is different. Since I'm importing store from 'redux', shouldn't the Redux type definition apply?

Comment: @Fabian, it looks like the two definitions are basically equivalent (except one takes type parameters, the docs one does not)

Comment: I'm assuming I'd need to install the libdef through flow-typed to pass in type parameters? I'm curious because I'm basing my project off of this (https://github.com/reduxjs/redux/tree/master/examples/todos-flow/src), and it directly `import type { store as ReduxStore ... } from 'redux'` (src/types/index.js)